# Add text watermark in print mode using css that works for all major browsers?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying add a simple text watermark that I want to appear for each page that it will get printed on and look reasonable on Firefox, IE and Chrome.
I've gone through all the related threads that I could find and have applied the suggested answers, but to no avail. Either it appears fine on every page, but doesn't show on the first page (Firefox). Or it only appears on the first page (Chrome). Or doesn't show at all.

I was wondering, is there a standard way to do css watermarks that works for all browsers that I may have missed somehow?

For those curious as to what my html/css looks like at the moment:

```
<div class="watermark">This is a watermark!</div>

@media print {    
    .watermark {
        display: inline;
        position: fixed !important;
        opacity: 0.25;
        font-size: 3em;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 1000;
        top:700x;
        right:5px;
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: This isn't just for watermarking images, otherwise as suggested I should use an image editor. This is for watermarking pages of document content (sections of text of various sizes).

Comment: this is not a CSS task... CSS is made for displaying web pages regardless of the printed version format. Use PDF instead

Comment: You would need to place `class="watermark"` on an element on every page.  You can't just have it once.

Answer (score 4):

The real problem is that you need a `.watermark` at the bottom of *each* printed page, but CSS has no concept of these printed pages.

The best you could probably do is to use the [page-break-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) CSS attribute to force a page break at certain points, then you could position your watermark just before that.

Something like (untested):

```
@media all {
  .watermark {
    display: none;
    background-image: url(...);
    float: right;
  }

  .pagebreak {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  .watermark {
    display: block;
  }

  .pagebreak {
    display: block;
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}

<body>
  some content for page 1...

  <div class="watermark"></div>
  <div class="pagebreak"></div>

  some content for page 2...

  <div class="watermark"></div>
  <div class="pagebreak"></div>
</body>
```

Really I think those 2 classes could just be the same element, but this seemed more understandable in code.

The down side here of course is that you need to manually specify where each page break happens, and realistically, if someone prints your webpage on a 4"x6" notecard, its going to be radically different than standard size paper. But still, it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in css, simply because it won't work.

Think of this, the user just removes your css, gets your image URLs and copies the images, without the watermark. Right click 'save image url' will also bypass css.

There are two good ways to add watermarks that are fail-safe.

**Edit the actual images**

If you have control over the images, such as if you are building a photography portfolio, just batch process them in your image editor and add the watermarks before you upload them to the web.

This is a good idea because then your images are ready watermarked regardless of where you use them, so they're social media / promo pack ready etc.

**Do it on request**

Set up an .htaccess rule that intercepts any image requests and redirects them via some server side code that uses an image processing library to add the watermark and return the binary image data. You can cache a watermarked image with a hash code and check for a watermarked version existing first that will allow you to bypass the processing.

This means that any image request, regardless of whether it comes from css, HTML, or a direct URL will serve a watermarked image. Do use some logic to skip any images used for the decoration of your site, otherwise you'll get watermarked in unexpected places!

The advantage here is that the original image is untouched, if you update your watermark, perhaps as part of a rebranding, you won't need to update all your images.

Another advantage of this approach is that you can apply it to any images, even if you don't create them - for example, if you have users uploading images to your site. Care should be taken with this however, before you watermark, make sure you have the right to watermark the image.

Comment: This isn't strictly for images otherwise yes, watermarking them in an image editor is the best option.
This is for displaying document content (sections of text mostly).
Sorry, I probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: fair comment, pdfs is a good plan then, unfortunately, any html or css can just be removed by a user - you could take a bank-note approach and make it really complicated and convoluted to remove the watermark!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I successfully managed to use watermark on every page in print preview

**HTML:**

```
<!-- place this only once in page -->
<div style="opacity: .5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);" class="watermark"></div>

<!-- place this in your table thead -->
<div style="opacity: .5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);" class="watermark_print"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.watermark_print{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("{{{watermark}}}") no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 99999999;
    border: none !important;
    background-size: 400px !important;
}
div.watermark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("{{{watermark}}}") no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 99999999;
    border: none !important;
    background-size: 400px !important;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

@media print {
    div.watermark {
        display: none;
    }
    div.watermark_print {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        inset: 0;
    }
}
```

That should do the trick, we have two watermark, one in HTML page review and another hidden in normal view but in print preview, we show it and because we are repeating table header in every page so we have this watermark on every page.

Answer (score 0):

**issue reason**.
print not support background-image.

**This is my solution.**
1.Absoluted position for Main elements(need to print div).
2.add  element

```
<style>
.mainContend{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}
.watermark{
    opacity: .8;
}
</style>
<script>
var addWatermark = function () {
        var bodHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
        //imge size is 1000*400px
        var imgNum = Math.floor(bodHeight/400) ;
        var template = '<img src="../img/icon/watermark.png" class="watermark">';
        var innerHTML;
        //create image number
        for(var i = 0;i < imgNum;i++){
            innerHTML +=template;
        }
        // innerHTML.appendTo("#reportContent);
        $("#reportContent").append(innerHTML);

    }
window.onload = addWatermark;
</script>
<div id="reportContent">
    <div class="mainContend" id="mainContend">
      content reportContentreportContentreportContent
    </div>
</div>
```